# Interactive Report Varchar2 Limit? (APEX 5.0)

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have 2 interactive reports that display on a page, a report that shows the data of forms submitted, and a file report that shows the files inserted. The main report has 9 columns, the majority being `VARCHAR2(4000)`. The longest value we have in there though is 1110 characters. But we keep getting the `ORA-06502: PL/SQL Numeric or Value Error: Character string too small`. If we don't display these columns, everything is fine. From what I can gather, an Interactive Report row has a limit of 32k, but we shouldn't be close to breaking 8k per row.

What are the actual limits for Interactive Reports, because I can't find anything solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit is 32K per row and it includes column values and HTML text that gets generated for each row of interactive report.  Try removing links or custom HTML, if any.

Comment: I believe this to be the problem (Sorry I've been off work for two weeks). We're trying to pass values through the link column, and that must be the issue.